# How to pass iterator to lambda function for my target element?

Tags: c++, vector, lambda, iterator

I want to find a element in an vector suppose:
`vector:vector<int> input = {11, 12, 15, 11, 13}; target element:11;`

My code:

```
  auto mylambda = [&target](const int &a)
    {
        return a == target;
    };
    vector<int>::iterator it = find_if(input.begin(), input.end(), mylambda);

    while (it != input.end())
    {
        cout << "Found item: " << *it << endl;
        int index = std::distance(input.begin(), it);
        cout << "Index number: " << index << endl;
        it++;
        it = find_if(it, input.end(), mylambda);
    }
```

It works fine with output:

```
Found item: 11
Index number: 0
Found item: 11
Index number: 3
```

I have to have my iterator value also in the lambda function.Consider something like this:

```
auto mylambda = [&target](const int &a)
    {
      //cout << distance(input.begin(), it) << endl;
      return a == target;
    };
```

The commented line.
Is there a way to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your compiler not tell you what is wrong when you uncomment that line (it has to do with your capture list)? Anyway, the correct approach most likely is to put the `cout << distance(...)` with the rest of the information being printed on screen i.e. outside the lambda. And if you do so, you can use the simpler `std::fin(it, input.end());` approach for your code.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that we can copy paste into a compiler and reproduce the problem/error.

Comment: the c++ standard algorithms are great if you want to do what they support, if you want to do something different you're better off just writing a for loop

Comment: Can you explain why do you need `it` in lambda? Even if you do pass it, it won't have any meaningful value until first `find_if` returns, so you'd generally need two lambdas - one for first `find_if` before loop and the other for any further calls inside loop.

Comment: I want to utilise the iterator value inside my lambda function.Consider something like I pass another 'vector<bool> visited' in capture clause.When it finds the element.I want to make visited[i]=true i.e where i is index which I get from the iterator.

Comment: That does not explain why you don't want to use the iterator **outside** of the lambda function, i.e. in the scope where it is returned by `find` or `find_if`

Comment: @PIYUSHTAILOR Re: _"where i is index which I get from the iterator"_ - For that you don't even need the iterator. Please see `idx` in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `std::vector` stores its data in a contiguous chunk of memory, you *can* get the index (distance from element 0) of the current element in the lambda by subtracting the address of the current element with the address of the first element - and from that index you can also get an iterator:

```cpp
auto mylambda = [&](const int &a) {

    std::size_t idx = std::distance(&*input.cbegin(), &a);
    auto it = std::next(input.begin(), idx);

    return a == target;
};
```

- `idx` is here the index of the current element
- `it` is here an iterator to the current element

Alternatively, keep a running counter:

```cpp
auto mylambda = [&target, idx = 0u](const int &a) mutable {
    // idx is here the index of the current element
    // auto it = std::next(input.begin(), idx); // if you even need an iterator
    ++idx;
    return a == target;
};
```